# Boosting Solr Range Query

Tags: solr

Is there a way to boost based on a range query in solr.

I've tried adding the boost to the end of the range, but it doesn't seem to apply the boost to the score.  I've run the query without the "(*:* ||" to ensure that I'm getting results that are both inside and outside the range.  The score reflects that boosting is taking place, but the items that match the boosted portion of the query do not recieve extra points.

Smaple Query:

```
q=lastName:(Smith) (*:* || dob:[1980-09-30T12:09:42.3804564-07:00Z TO 1983-09-30T12:09:42.3844564-07:00Z]^100)
```

Does anyone know how I can get solr to incorporate the boosted field into the result scores?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to this, but I think you would use a boost query to elevate those results:

```
&bq=dob:[1980-09-30T12:09:42.3804564-07:00Z TO 1983-09-30T12:09:42.3844564-07:00Z]^100
```